# Java Swing - GUI not refreshing or freeze after java 1.8 updates

Tags: java, swing, java-8, frame

I have a working application, which working fine in Java 1.6 and 1.7 and even 1.8 update 31. I just update my Java today 1.8 update 45 and found my application interface having issue. For an example: 
[image]
This is my working application screen. This is what it should be, but after the update its become like this (below):
[image]
Once I get the not functioning interface, I need to click on the area or I need to minimize the application and open again to revert back to normal.

**Code**

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
tab.setTabPlacement(2);
frame.add(tab, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
ComparePanelMin cmp = new ComparePanelMin();
tab.add("Compare", cmp);
ReportPanelMin rp = new ReportPanelMin();
tab.add("Reporting (For Single Compare)", rp);
ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
idx = tab.getSelectedIndex();
}
```

Above code to switch between the tabs. Any advice or reference links is highly appreciated.
**EDITED**
**DeadLock**
[image]

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I think JVM is unable to paint/repaint the JFrame. By minimizing and restoring the window you are forcing JVM to repaint thus getting the proper output. Does it throw any exceptions?

Comment: @Blip nope, no any exceptions at system level. Is there anywhere we can log file in JVM level. To check JVM is unable to paint/repaint the Jframe.

Comment: Did you try to run in from command prompt?

Comment: @Blip this is a Java Swing project, no idea how I can run this in CMD. When I run the main class, it shows error since cannot find other classes which I defined in the main class.

Comment: if this is a jar file then type *java -jar <jarfile.jar>* else if from top level folder of your package type *java path/to/main/<mainfile.class>*

Answer (score 2):

I guess its an issue of deadlock I faced a similar issue of GUI freezing with Swing. Nothing worked out so I had to dig into the code of Swing and I found some really crappy codes which were causing the dead lock and it was very difficult to trace even in the thread dump.
you can try these tools and check for dead lock
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jvisualvm.html

you can search how to identify dead lock using these tools

Also the way you're adding tab in frame is not the right way you should add it using frame.getContentPane().add(tab, BorderLayout.SOUTH)

Comment: No deadlock detected. I have edited my question with the screen shot

Comment: Seems like you're using jconsole ,deadlock check doesn't work that well. Try jvisualvm and check its Tread tab for  threads and see if you could draw some conclusion.Not necessary the its a deadlock may be some other issue.Also make sure you perform modification in SwingUtilities.invokeLater thread

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar issues if not all Swing components are created on the event dispatch thread (EDT).

Make **absolutely** sure that even your initial `JFrame` is created/shown from the EDT:

```
  public class HelloWorldSwing {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello Swing");

      // Your init code here...

      frame.setVisible(true);
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Schedule creation of UI on the EDT
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
  }
}
```